# llvm module can not be found

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I tried to follow the instructions in http://releases.llvm.org/2.6/docs/tutorial/JITTutorial1.html to have make my own function and produce llvm IR. However, executing
 c++ -g tut1.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs core` -o tut1, I am stopped by:
"llvm/Module.h": No such file or Directory.

Does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

2.6 is very old. Try newer LLVM and tutorial, like [this one](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/BuildingAJIT1.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May I ask how can I make my own IR?(Is there any tutorial for making a code in IR for myself?)

Comment: @user3126804 You can generate it from C/C++ code using `clang -S -emit-llvm file.c`. Or, you can write it yourself, here is the reference: http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html